# Java post method from HTTPS

Tags: java, https, cryptography

I have a problem with POST in https page ia  use this code

```
 URL url = new URL("https://<website>.aspx?g=postmessage&f=234");
    Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("forum:_ctl0:Subject", filName);
    params.put("forum:_ctl0:edit", numcert );


    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }
    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new
    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; System.out.print((char)c));
  }
```

And when I am run it it gives me that errors

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
 sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at single_window.my.MainWatch.Trup(MainWatch.java:51)
at single_window.my.MainWatch.main(MainWatch.java:99)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find
 valid
 certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
Source)
 at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
 ... 21 more
```

i used that's method in the loop for

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

    Path faxFolder = Paths.get("\\test\\in");
    WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    faxFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);


    boolean valid = true;
    do {
        WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();

        for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
            if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
                String fileName = event.context().toString();

                 for (File myFile : new File("\\test\\in").listFiles()){



                            User user=null;
                            ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
                            user=mapper.readValue(myFile, User.class);
                            //System.out.println
                            numcert=(user.getNum());
                            filName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-14);
                            //System.out.println(filName);
                            delay(2000);
                            Trup();
                            delay(5000);
                            Path original = Paths.get("\\test\\in\\"+myFile.getName()); 
                            Path destination = Paths.get("\\test\\out\\"+myFile.getName()); 

                             Files.move(original, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); 






                 }

                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File Created:" + fileName);
            }
        }
        valid = watchKey.reset();

    } while (valid);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your HTTPS is not certified one, or your system does not allow it, you need to put into the trusted zone like with your browsed do. The difference is that you use the keytool what shipped with JDK. You can find many tutorials on net for this process.

When SSLHandshakeException occurs, usually this is the problem, or the certification was expired.

Comment: How to bypass verification?

Answer (score 1):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This means that the web server or the URL you are connecting to does not have a valid certificate from an authorized CA. But however, being a programmer you would want to find out the alternative way to solve this issue.

What you need to do is to import the server certificate and install it in your JDK's key-store. Just follow these steps and you will be able to get rid of that error.

1. First of all you copy the URL that you are connecting to and paste it in your browser. Let us say you are using IE. Just paste the url in the address bar and press enter.
2. You will now probably see a dialog box warning you about the certificate. Now click on the 'View Certificate' and install the certificate. Ignore any warning messages.
3. Now that the server certificate is installed in your computer, your browser will not warn you when you visit the same site again. But however your JRE dumb as it is does not yet know about this certificate's existence until you add it to its key-store. Usually you will use the key-tool to manage certificates. Key-tool is a command-line utility with numerous arguments that allow you to create and manage key-stores for housing digital certificates. For the complete documentation of key-tool see: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html
4. You can list the current certificates contained within a key-store using they key-tool -list command. The initial password for the cacerts key-store is change it. For example:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Citrix\Citrix Extranet Server\SGJC\jre\bin>keytool -list -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts

   Enter keystore password: changeit
   ```

   You will then see the something like this:

   ```
   Keystore type: jks
   Keystore provider: SUN
   Your keystore contains 11 entries:
   engweb, Wed Apr 11 16:22:49 EDT 2001, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 8C:24:DA:52:7A:4A:16:4B:8E:FB:67:44:C9:D2:E4:16

   thawtepersonalfreemailca, Fri Feb 12 15:12:16 EST 1999, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 1E:74:C3:86:3C:0C:35:C5:3E:C2:7F:EF:3C:AA:3C:D9

   thawtepersonalbasicca, Fri Feb 12 15:11:01 EST 1999, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): E6:0B:D2:C9:CA:2D:88:DB:1A:71:0E:4B:78:EB:02:41

   verisignclass3ca, Mon Jun 29 13:05:51 EDT 1998, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 78:2A:02:DF:DB:2E:14:D5:A7:5F:0A:DF:B6:8E:9C:5D

   thawteserverca, Fri Feb 12 15:14:33 EST 1999, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): C5:70:C4:A2:ED:53:78:0C:C8:10:53:81:64:CB:D0:1D

   thawtepersonalpremiumca, Fri Feb 12 15:13:21 EST 1999, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 3A:B2:DE:22:9A:20:93:49:F9:ED:C8:D2:8A:E7:68:0D

   verisignclass4ca, Mon Jun 29 13:06:57 EDT 1998, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 1B:D1:AD:17:8B:7F:22:13:24:F5:26:E2:5D:4E:B9:10

   verisignclass1ca, Mon Jun 29 13:06:17 EDT 1998, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 51:86:E8:1F:BC:B1:C3:71:B5:18:10:DB:5F:DC:F6:20

   verisignserverca, Mon Jun 29 13:07:34 EDT 1998, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 74:7B:82:03:43:F0:00:9E:6B:B3:EC:47:BF:85:A5:93

   thawtepremiumserverca, Fri Feb 12 15:15:26 EST 1999, trustedCertEntry,

   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 06:9F:69:79:16:66:90:02:1B:8C:8C:A2:C3:07:6F:3A

   verisignclass2ca, Mon Jun 29 13:06:39 EDT 1998, trustedCertEntry,

    Certificate fingerprint (MD5): EC:40:7D:2B:76:52:67:05:2C:EA:F2:3A:4F:65:F0:D8
   ```
5. Now you have to add the previosly installed certificate to this keystore. To add, begin by exporting your CA Root certificate as a DER-encoded binary file and save it as `C:\root.cer`. (you can view the installed certificates under

> Tools->'Internet Options' ->Content->Certificates.

Once you open the certificates, locate the one you just installed under 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities". Select the right one and click on 'export'. You can now save it (DER encoded binary) under your c: drive.

6. Then use the `keytool -import` command to import the file into your cacerts keystore. For example:

   ```
   -alias myprivateroot -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -file c:\root.cer

   Enter keystore password: changeit

   Owner: CN=Division name, OU=Department, O=Your Company, L=Anytown,   ST=NC, C=US, EmailAddress=you@company.com

   Issuer: CN=Division name, OU=Department, O=Your Company, L=Anytown, ST=NC, C=US, EmailAddress=you@company.com

   Serial number: 79805d77eecfadb147e84f8cc2a22106

   Valid from: Wed Sep 19 14:15:10 EDT 2001 until: Mon Sep 19 14:23:20 EDT 2101

   Certificate fingerprints:

   MD5: B6:30:03:DC:6D:73:57:9B:F4:EE:13:16:C7:68:85:09

   SHA1: B5:C3:BB:CA:34:DF:54:85:2A:E9:B2:05:E0:F7:84:1E:6E:E3:E7:68

   Trust this certificate? [no]: yes

   Certificate was added to keystore
   ```
7. Now run `keytool -list` again to verify that your private root certificate was added:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Citrix\Citrix Extranet Server\SGJC\jre\bin>keytool -list -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts
   ```

You will now see a list of all the certificates including the one you just added.

This confirms that your private root certificate has been added to the Extranet server cacerts keystore as a trusted certificate authority.

For more details please follow this URL:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll trying this and told about result of your instructions

Comment: It's doesn't help, I have same problems, perhaps this is due with export close key certificates?

Comment: if I must enter login and pass to forum that's method working?